# Force UIViewController to layout correctly without bringing it onto the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, storyboard

I am having some difficulty with the following problem. I have laid out a UIViewController in Storyboard with the correct constraints. It has all the same views as the UIViewController on the screen at the present. I am using this new UIViewController for some resizing. Therefore, I would like to initialize this UIViewController, layout all the subviews, according to the constraints I have given it, and then use the UIView's frames for the primary UIViewController. Since I never need this secondary UIViewController, it is never displayed.

I instantiate the secondary UIViewController as follows:

```
secondaryVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondaryVCId") as? secondaryVC
```

This works fine, but getting the positions of the subviews, the most important thing, does not. Even though the view is sized correctly, (i.e. when `secondaryVC.view.size` is printed, it is the same as `primaryVC.view.size`) but the subviews still think that the view is 600 x 600. I have tried many things to force the subviews to layout again, but none seem to work, other than adding the view as a subview, (i.e. `primaryVC.view.addSubview(secondaryVC.view)`) which I would prefer not to do, (because I would then have to remove it again.)

Answer (score 2):

Did you ever try with

```
secondaryVC.view.setNeedsLayout()
secondaryVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Moreover, you can't use secondaryVC's view from viewDidLoad, its size not loaded yet.

One way that I ever use, I created a protocol. and let secondaryVC call protocol to primaryVC when secondaryVC finished viewWillAppear / viewDidLayoutSubviews.